# How to get URL of the image from Facebook graph response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a Facebook wall feed for an mobile app using Ionic/AngularJS framework. I need help to retrieve the direct image link of an published photo at my fanpage. The **picture** object from the JSON data display an very small thumbnail of the original photo so if I increase the size using CSS it losses the quality.I am using the **link** value URL as img ng-src but doesnt display anything since the link is not to the image itself but the link to the post on facebook.

Below are my codes,
Inside view:

```
<ion-content padding="true" ng-controller="FacebookCtrl" class="has-footer">
           <label class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="query" >
            </label>
            <ion-list ng-repeat="item in news | filter:query | limitTo:20">
           <ion-item  ng-if="item.type == 'photo'">
               <h2 >{{item.caption}}</h2>
               <p>{{item.message}}</p>
               <img ng-src="{{item.link}}"/><br>
               <i class="icon ion-android-favorite"></i> {{item.likes.data.length}} Pelqime
               <p>Publikuar me: {{item.created_time | date: 'medium' }}  </p>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item  ng-if="item.type == 'link'">
               <h2 >{{item.name}}</h2>
               <p>{{item.message}}</p>
                    <img ng-src="{{item.picture}}"/><br>
               <i class="icon ion-android-favorite"></i> {{item.likes.data.length}} Pelqime
               <p>Publikuar me: {{item.created_time | date: 'medium' }}  </p>
           </ion-item>
           <ion-item  ng-if="item.type == 'video'">
               <h2 >{{item.name}}</h2>
               <p>{{item.message}}<br>
                    {{item.source}}
               </p>
               <video width="400" controls src="{{item.source}}">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
               </video>

               <i class="icon ion-android-favorite"></i> {{item.likes.data.length}} Pelqime
               <p>Publikuar me: {{item.created_time | date: 'medium' }}  </p>
           </ion-item>
           </ion-list>

        </ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('FacebookCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/radioopendimi/feed?access_token=APP_ID|APP_Secret').then(function(resp){
        $scope.news = resp.data.data;
        console.log('Success: ',resp);
    }, function(err){
        console.error('Error: ',err);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the field `full_picture`, that should contain the largest version of the image that Facebook has available.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/radioopendimi/feed?fields=full_picture,[…]&access_token=…
```

Be aware that when using the `fields` parameter, you must specify *all* fields you want to get, otherwise you will only get the `id` by default.

Comment: It works thank you, I've just started using facebook graph and its not too well documented as is Youtube API for example.. Anyway thank you!